# Understanding config.xml: What is <config><global><models><My_Mage>?

Tags: configuration

I'm new to Magento and I have a `config.xml` which stands for a module configuration as far as I've learned.

I have problems to understand (also to locate some sort of documentation for that, [Magentos `config.xml` Reference](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/module_config.xml#global) is totally no-saying to me) on this very basic level already. For example the following excerpt from `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Mage>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </My_Mage>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <My_Mage>
                <class>My_Mage_Model</class>
            </My_Mage>
            <!-- ... --->
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

What is the part in `config/globals/models` about?

I guessed it was about some file on disk, however I can not find any file related to the `<class>` "`My_Mage_Model`".

For what does that part stand for?:

```
        <models>
            <My_Mage>
                <class>My_Mage_Model</class>
            </My_Mage>
```

Any hints greatly appreceated.

Comment: Looks like this is the *base class name* for all the models in that module. It means, that all *model class names* are prefixed with it (e.g. `class My_Mage_Model_ConcreteModel`). The module name is given within the `<My_Mage>` tag, corresponding to the module directory. See https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18269/understanding-config-xml-what-is-configglobalmodelsmy-mage - Still not sure about `<globals>`.

Comment: <global> means all things that are used globally, e.g. helper-, block- and model-classes, in comparison to things used only for <frontend> or <adminhtml>, e.g. observers or layout updates. If you search the web for material on how to create an own extension, many of these things will be explained. <My_Mage> is technically not only the class name, but also the module's name and the name of the directories your files are in.

Comment: @simonthesorcerer: Thanks for your comment, if you can suggest a good developer resource for modules and magento online, your sharing is highly appreceated. I have problems to find distinct resources via google, the knowledge base article I linked was a good relief, so suggestions welcome in case you know a snappy one.

Comment: The correct links are: [Magento for Developers: Part 1 - Introduction to Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento) and [Magento for Developers: Part 2 - The Magento Config](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-2-the-magento-config) - I pasted the wrong one in my first comment.

Comment: Hi hakre, is this what you are searching for? http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Magento-Extension-Developers-Guide-v1.0.pdf There is also the MagentoU-portal, where you can watch about 40h video material for free

Comment: @simonthesorcerer this looks very good. On Magento U I didn't found any freely accessible videos, I guess it needs some account but I don't have mine on this computer right now, so will give it a try mid next week. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node that contains `<class>My_Mage_Model</class>` registers all classes prefixed with My_Mage_Model as models that can be utilized using the `Mage::getModel` method.  There is most likely a directory at `<root>/app/code/local/My/Mage/Model/` and this is where you put any models for the "My" module.

If you were going to write a helper class for this module you would follow the same pattern - put the class in `<root>/app/code/local/My/Mage/Helper/` and add a node within `<global>` like

```
<helper>
  <My_Mage>
    <class>My_Mage_Helper</class>
  </My_Mage>
 </helper>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<global>` node contains definations that should be shared between all scopes (admin, frontend,  adminhtml, default) 
`<models>` node is used for declaring models in your module. 
`<My_Mage>` is a unique string to model declaration of your module. But mostly we are using here is `Namespace_Modulename` as it is also unique. 
`<class>` node contains the path to your models folder of this particular module.

Magento will traverse in your module's model folder as `app/code/codePool/My(Namespace)/Mage(Modulename)/Models`

Modules's declaration is done in `<modules>` node.

```
>     <modules>
>         <My_Mage(Namespace_Modulename)> // app/code/codePool/Namespace/Modulename
>             <version>1.0.0</version>
>         </My_Mage>
>     </modules>
```